# SolidWorks ratio issue with printing in landscape

Tags: windows-xp, printer, cad

We run SolidWorks 2010 on XP.  On one workstation when printing to the plotter in a 1:1 ratio in landscape mode it's off by small increments.  He needs to adjust manually from 1:1 to 1:1.009 (for example) in order to correctly print 1:1.  The increments by which it's off varies from drawing to drawing.  None of the other workstations have this issue.

All five of the workstations have the same settings and all print to one networked plotter.  Three out of five have the same graphics card.  Scale to fit is not checked.

I read this site often, but this is the first time I've posted.  I'm hoping someone here has run across this before.  Thanks.